# Сортировка MYSQL Order BY с условием

Tags: mysql

Прошу помочь, как я могу реализовать ORDER BY с условием IF else. если это возможно! Вот такое нужно преобразовать в нужный синтаксис, если mysql позволяет:

```
SELECT * from `table` ORDER BY (`price1` if `hm1`>0 else `price2` if `hm2`>0 else `price3`), `name`
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `hm1`>0 THEN `price1`
              WHEN `hm2`>0 THEN `price2`
              ELSE `price3`
              END, 
         `name`
```

Comment: А если у меня и hm1 и hm2 > 0, то сортировка будет по price1 или price2 ?

Comment: @Антон Если вышестоящее условие истинно, выполняется его действие, дальнейшие условия не проверяются. Как и в любом CASE. Так что по `price1`.

Comment: Спасибо! Последний вопрос, могу ли я после THEN указывать несколько столбцов, например:
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `hm1`>0 THEN `price1`, `aaa` DESC
              WHEN `hm2`>0 THEN `price2`, `bbb`
              ELSE `price3`, `ccc` 
              END, 
         `name`

Comment: @Антон Нет. CASE возвращает только одно значение. Используйте несколько последовательных CASE, наращивая условия при необходимости. А вот с DESC будут трудности - возвращается значение, а не выражение. Для числового поля ещё можно использовать `-field` вместо `field DESC`, для даты `-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field)`, а вот со строковыми будут проблемы...